# In search of double barrier out option on a BM

Tags: options, brownian-motion, exotics, barrier

We have a BM $X_t$ with $dX_t=\sigma dB_t$ ($X_0$ not necessarily zero!) under the risk neutral measure $\Bbb Q$. Given upper barrier $U$, lower barrier $L$, "strike" $K$ such that $L<X_0<U, L<K < U$,  rebate $b$, maturity $T$, and define $m:=\min_{0\le t\le T}X_t$ and $M:=\max_{0\le t\le T}X_t$. Suppose the terminal payoff function is 
 $$|X_T - K|I(L\le m \text{ and } M\le U) + bI(\text{otherwise})$$

Suppose in addition a constant discount rate $r>0$. Is an analytical formula for this double barrier out option's price, i.e. 
$$e^{-rT}\Bbb E^{\Bbb Q}\left[|X_T - K|I(L\le m \text{ and } M\le U) + bI(\text{otherwise})\right]$$
 possible? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Looks like Brownian Bridge is a good start. At least I can see it lead to explicit integral forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well tackled problem in the GBM case. See

> Geman/Yor (1996), [Pricing and Hedging Double-Barrier Options: A Probabilistic Approach](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-9965.1996.tb00122.x). Mathematical Finance, 6(4), p. 365-378

among other references. Though in practice finite differences or MC would be used to deal with discrete dividends, local and/or stochastic volatility, etc.

Comment: Thanks. However in my case the underlying follows a standard Brownian motion instead of a GBM. So they might be quite different.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it was for a BM rather than for a GBM. However the barrier in the $\mu$-drifted GBM case translates into a log barrier in the $\mu - \sigma^2/2$ drifted BM case so a similar approach should work, perhaps following that outlined in Pelsser Pricing double barrier options using Laplace transforms https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/19187200.pdf.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah the approach provided in your paper also works nicely for Bachelier model and leads to even simpler forms. The results are exponentially fast decaying Fourier series, and I think they should already be good enough for my use.